# Test multiple request in SOAP UI?

Tags: soapui

I want to test load balancing in my local by hitting my soap request multiple time, without hitting run button in soap UI. Can we do that? I don't know about groovy language. Can you please anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: soapUI has built-in load-testing capabilities. Just right-click on your project and look for the Launch LoadTestRunner context menu item. You'll need to do a little research at [Load Testing Basics](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html), no Groovy required.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `Groovy` script for this purpose.

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    def tCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["Test"]
    def tStep = tCase.testSteps["Request"]
    tStep.run(testRunner, context)
        Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```